# What is the proper switch configuration for the switch that is connected directly to ISP source?

Tags: routing, switch, switching, layer3, isp

[image: Updated Network Diagram]

The Question: What is the proper configuration for the L3 switch to be allowed to assign public IPs for the firewalls?

I guess All I need is that the switch L3 act as a layer 2 switch...Right?

Update
1- The Same ISP provides two public subnets /29 ( wan 1 and wan 2)
2- SFP connectors are connected to Cisco 3650
3- The Firewalls are Fortigate and they are working as Routers (NAT Mode).

I just need to know:

1. what is the ports configuration on the layer 3 switch that will be connected to the ISP?
2. what is the ports configuration on the layer 3 switch that will be connected to the Firewalls? Or any device will be connected directly to the L3 switch to have a public IP?

Comment: That depends on several factors. You need to give us more information. We don't even know what the switch model is, so there is no way to give you a configuration, but we also need to know a lot more about the ISP connection. Is it a single connection to one ISP, multiple connections to one ISP, or single connections to two ISPs? Can the firewalls be configured as transparent firewalls? You need to include all the relevant information.

Comment: Sorry for my bad descriptions. I updated my question. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your network design is really correct. If you are going to introduce a SPoF (Single Point of Failure) by using the single switch, then why not just use a single firewall for both ISP connections? Then, you could eliminate the (unprotected) switch. Also, if the firewalls are doing the routing, why do you need routers inside the firewalls? Also, you don't normally connect the hosts directly to the routers. Could it be that those are switches? I believe you may be overthinking this. I would probably go with a single firewall and layer-3 switches inside for the routing.

Comment: What is your reason for using a switch here?  Media converter?  Do you need to run BGP with your ISP?

Comment: No, Not Need BGP... I updated the network diagram as you recommended... The circumstance is that The two fiber cables from ISP are connected to the Cisco switch then a single connection to the next Cisco Switch, Then Single connection to the Firewall. The firewall has two WAN connection (WAN1 and WAN2)... Actually, I don't know the credentials of both Cisco and I would replace them But The problem is How can I configure the new two switches to make everything works as it is?

Comment: Sorry @RonMaupin : I am not professional enough to ask the correct question :( But I am doing my best to describe my issue. Many thanks

Comment: Well if you don't know the credentials of the switches, you cannot configure them. You probably  want a VLAN for each ISP network (assuming the two connections are separate networks), or one VLAN if the two connections use the same network. You will need to be able to log into the switches to create the VLAN(s).

Comment: Also, we can give you some configurations, but we need to know the existing switch configurations, and the specific switch interfaces used for the connections on the diagram.

Comment: I can't log in to the two switches, No Way! also recovery feature is disabled... I wanna to replace the two switches... So, I would ask you to recommend a topology and configuration for the ports which will be used to connect the firewall with two public IPs (WAN 1 and WAN 2) ... Regarding the Public IPs, They are two subnets /29... So, I would assign one public IP from each subnet to the firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you'd want to avoid plugging a switch directly into the ISP (even a layer 3) but if your Fortigate is acting as a router, you can use the switch by doing the following:

Assign it one of the IP's from your ISP. Switch your links to trunk link connecting to the router, and access links to the end users. Set your default gateway (including your gateway of last resort back to the ISP) and you should have a bare bones network.

You can spread out and run VLANs, but I would start with it as easy as possible, make sure it works, then add customization one piece at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Both 3650 layer3 switch acts as layer2 devices . Natting  should done on fortigate firewall . A default route should Configured in firewall pointing towards gateways of ISP .

So nat translation happen in firewall . Frame outbound security policy for internet access .

Souce as :LAN subnet

Destination as : ANY

Action : allow

Services : Https (or others)

Frame inbound policy in fortigate firewall  for incoming traffic to access internal hosted server resources from internet.

Answer (score -1):

First step is to understand the topology of your network ,that we can use for example i used ring topology for our company......
ring topology is used for inconvience network,if one side is blocked ,we can connect with another side....
then we can configure the switch ,set the name for switch and we can use the interface either trunk or access port....
then we will pass the Vlan for security process....
port security is used for connect a single system with that mac address....
then we want to create SNMP for network link down issues.....
vlan can be tagges or un tagged